# Should Java DTOs which resides only in server be serializeble?

Tags: java, jboss

In a JBoss **clustered** environment should the Java DTOs which resides only in server be **serializable** in order to be communicated properly within each JBoss instance? These DTOs I'm referring to could be exchanged between many server to server APIs. But never will reach to client side. My concern here is since this JBoss server environment I'm referring is a **clustered** environment there could be calls coming from different JBoss instances.

Comment: When server A calls a remote method exposed by server B, it's acting as a client. If the communication protocol requires objects to be serializable, whether the caller is the "client", or another server, the information still has to go over the wires.

Comment: @JB Nizet What do you mean by protocol here? TCP/IP ? How can we determine on which protocol the clustered JBoss setup runs on?

Comment: No, I simply mean the way two parties communicate. If a client C needs a DTO to be serializable to be able to communicate with a server A, and a server B wants to communicate to the server A in the same way as C does, then the DTO also needs to be serializable: whether you consider B as a client or as a server doesn't change anything. You're not aying anything about how the exchanges between servers are made, so we can't tell if the DTO needs to be serializable or not. What matters is HOW they communicate. Not if they are servers or clients.

Comment: Thanks! Now I think I'm making sense of it. These DTO's not exposed through any **remote** method. They are used in simple java API methods. There are many services deployed in same JBoss and each service communicate through these APIs. Therefore I this case I assume that these DTO's does not need to be serialized.